# How do I print formatting marks in Word 2010

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2010

I'd like to print formatting marks such as space indicators "·" or paragraph signs "¶" from a Word document so that I can review them off-screen.

It seems like this should be simple. Instructions that work for Word 2007 do not seem to work for 2010, as the hidden formatting marks show up on the print preview but do not actually print out. See https://askdrexel.drexel.edu/app/answers/detail/a_id/2354/~/how-to%3A-show-the-formatting-marks-while-printing-a-document-in-word-2007.

I'd like to avoid wholesale regex/find+replace solutions that replace them with the real (that is, printable) character.

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, had the approach worked for Word 2007 it would very likely also work for Word 2010. I think the problem is that AskDrexel is wrong - these non-printing characters do not print out of Word 2007 (at least not with my understanding of their instructions).

A 'conventional' solution would be to take a screenshot with non-printing characters displayed but my guess is that you have a lot of pages, in which case regex does indeed seem the least impractical option - after on-screen editing!